# How do I write this function x^.3*(1-x)^.7

Tags: r, function, floating-point

I try to write

```
testFunc = function(x){x^0.3 * (1-x)^0.7}
```

but when I try

```
testFunc(2)
```

R returns `NaN` result (for any `x`>1). How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you try to raise a negative floating-point value to a fractional exponent, you'll always get `NaN`. This is not necessarily the mathematically correct answer - for example, we know that the cube root of -8 (-8^(1/3)) "should" be -2 ((-2)^3 == -8). From `?"^"`:

> Users are sometimes surprised by the value returned, for example
>        why ‘(-8)^(1/3)’ is ‘NaN’.  For double inputs, R makes use of IEC
>        60559 arithmetic on all platforms, together with the C system
>        function ‘pow’ for the ‘^’ operator.  The relevant standards
>        define the result in many corner cases.  In particular, the result
>        in the example above is mandated by the C99 standard.  On many
>        Unix-alike systems the command ‘man pow’ gives details of the
>        values in a large number of corner cases.

If you really want to raise negative values to fractional powers, you could use `as.complex()`:

```
as.complex(-1)^0.7
[1] -0.5877853+0.809017i
```

Your function would be

```
function(x){x^0.3 * as.complex(1-x)^0.7}
```

but you might need to rethink the mathematical foundations of whatever you're trying to do ...